Trying to build a VS Code extension. How can I show a Webview View in the Panel section of VS Code?
I would like to show a webview in the section labeled D:

In my attempt, I am able to add a new tab to the Panel but it always says "There is no data provider registered that can provide view data."

The "contributes" property in my package.json looks like the following:
"contributes": {
        "viewsContainers": {
            "panel": [
                {
                    "id": "myCustomPanel",
                    "title": "My Custom Panel",
                    "icon": "$(file-code)"
                }
            ]
        },
        "views": {
            "myCustomPanel": [
                {
                    "id": "myCustomTab",
                    "name": "My Tab"
                }
            ]
        },
        "activationEvents": [
            "*"
        ]
    },

and my extension.js looks like:
import * as vscode from "vscode";

class MyCustomPanelProvider implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
  constructor(private readonly context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {}

  public resolveWebviewView(
    webviewView: vscode.WebviewView,
    _context: vscode.WebviewViewResolveContext,
    _token: vscode.CancellationToken
  ) {
    console.log("resolveWebviewView called"); // Log to verify it's called

    // Allow scripts in the webview
    webviewView.webview.options = {
      enableScripts: true,
      localResourceRoots: [this.context.extensionUri]
    };

    // Set the HTML content
    webviewView.webview.html = this.getHtmlForWebview();
  }

  private getHtmlForWebview(): string {
    // Define your HTML content here
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Custom Panel</title>
  <style>
    body { font-family: sans-serif; padding: 10px; }
    h1 { color: #007acc; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello from My Custom Panel!</h1>
  <p>This is an HTML content displayed in the panel.</p>
</body>
</html>`;
  }
}

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  console.log("Extension activated"); // Log to verify activation

  const provider = new MyCustomPanelProvider(context);

  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider('myCustomTab', provider)
  );
}

export function deactivate() {}


I noticed that the resolveWebviewViewis never called and I don't really know why. I tried to follow the "Webview view" sample at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/webview-view-sample but could never get to render it in the panel either.

if you drag/drop a view from the activity bar the Panel is the ViewContainer
